# Turn on an alarm indefinitely when logic is true

Tags: piezo-buzzer

I would like to turn on the piezzo buzzer in the following simple schematic indefinitely when the logic is true i.e when both inputs to the AND gate are logic 1. The pulse in the second input can last a couple of seconds but the piezzo buzzer must still be on. In other words, I need only get a true condition once.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is known as a [latch or flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)). You can get them as an IC, or you can make them out of NAND or NOR gates, or even transistors.

Note that you may not be able to drive a buzzer directly from a logic output, you may need to add a transistor to supply more drive current.

Answer (score 1):

You need a latch or flip-flop as mentioned in the other answer. Make sure that you reset the latch or flip-flop at powerup otherwise the output of the latch/flip-flop will be unknown.